# How can magical creatures created from mana be prevented from using mana to perform spells?

Tags: magic, mythical-creatures

The moon is a celestial object that rotates around the earth and is made up of warpstone, a solidified form of mana. This warpstone radiates its energy toward earth, bathing the planet with waves of mana. This forms the basis of mana content within the environment, which is used by witches to conduct magical spells and rituals. This mana can gather and pool in large amounts within certain areas and become stable. In this instance, the mana may condense into solidified form. This serves as the basis for creating the mythical creatures in this world, created from mana and molded into a physical state. Some are humanoid, such as elves or goblins, and others are beast-like, such as griffons or sphinxes. All are intelligent beings that can either be beneficial or hostile toward humans depending on their temperament.

Wtiches are magic sensitive due to the inborn mana that they possess. This allows them to sense the external mana surrounding them and allows them to manipulate it using their own mana to perform spells. They can search out the best places for rituals, with places containing the highest content being the best locations for the most powerful spells. Magical creatures, however, are bound to their own locations in which they were formed. As these creatures were created in places of high mana content, they are relegated to these areas and are unable to venture out. This keeps them isolated from human populations unless sought out by individuals. As they were literally created from magic itself, it would be natural for them to be the strongest magic users on the planet. Their absolute closeness with the building blocks of mana should allow them to wield it with more ability than average people. However, it turns out that magical creatures are unable to use the mana surrounding them, preventing them from using magic at all.

Being created by magic has prevented them from accessing external mana to actually use magic. How could this be the case?

Comment: This sounds like the logic of Piers Anthony's Xanth books. The argument is that you can either use magic or be magic, but not both. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth

Comment: Well, your creature is not a cannibal, is it? Cannot use mana if magic uses the nearest mana, i.e. itself as fuel.

Comment: You haven't given us any rules for how "using magic" works... and that being the case, as noted, I see no reason why you can't just make this a restriction by authorial fiat.

Comment: What does it mean 'unable to use mana at all' and 'incapable of performing spells or rituals'? What would happen if a mythological creature attempted to use mana or perform a ritual? I think you would get better answers if you could provide a bit more information about the consequences of restrictions on mythological creatures. I also agree with Matthew that we need a bit more information about the magic system.

Comment: It looks like you're wanting us to brainstorm and make up rules of your world for you. Please remember that questions with many valid answers are too broad for this site.

Answer (score 3):

Mana has an extremely high level of cohesion.  Once particles of mana bond together into higher life forms, those particles are very hesitant to separate or disperse.

A witch, being made of something other than mana, can gather it, shape it and then cast it outwards to magical effect.  The loose mana rests within their hands once gathered and doesn't stick to those hands during the shaping and casting.  There is no binding affinity between the mana and the witch, so the energies can come and go as the witch desires.

Mythical creatures, being made of mana, can gather mana, but every particle of mana which responds to their call merges with them, becoming a permanent part of their magical selves.  They cannot shape it or caste it outward anymore than the witch could slice off a chunk of their own flesh.

For a mythical creature, magic is sort of like trying to kneed raw dough without coating your hands first with flour.  Every time you touch the forming dough loaf, it tears apart and sticks to you, ruining the recipe and making a mess.

Comment: And any creature that tries has doughy lumps of mana sticking to them, wiggling around and making their clothes not fit.  No other creatures want to get near because the mana will get on them too.  These unfortunate creatures must seek out the help of witches and endure the cackling, and the more cackling.

Comment: As mana given form, the effect of gathering mana is all they can manage. Surely, the strongest and most ancient of them could potentially gather enough mana to create sacrificial bits to hurl raw explosive mana as primitive spells and weapons of last resort.

Answer (score 1):

## Magic beings are magic-soluble:

Mana is a material, and as such is the source for magic. But people using magic aren't using up themselves when they cast a spell. They use and access something rather external to themselves. While that doesn't allow them limitless power, it means the mana isn't going to hurt them when things get slightly out of hand. They can shape and influence the magic without being carried away by it.

A being made of magic, however, owes their very existence to the stuff. A spell flowing though them is like washing water through a sculpture made of powdered sugar. Magic tears at their essence, and CASTING spells is the most intimate use of magic. A magical being using magic would literally be drawing energy out of what makes them up - like magic aging draining life force or casting hit points.

So even learning how to control spells would mean such a being had eroded their very existence. They might become deformed, or undead-looking as every little miss-step eroded their very being. Perhaps such beings COULD perform great deeds. The question is, could they survive it?

Besides, they are performing the equivalent of a powerful magic spell in simply existing. The fact they can't leave high-mana areas means they may be consuming so much mana simply to exist that they have nothing left to cast spells.

This doesn't mean you couldn't bypass these limitations. Perhaps if they keep the mana external to them (with wands, or magic devices) they could still use mana as magic spells. But at that point, they would be even LESS direct in it's use than a conventional mage.

Answer (score 1):

### Mana availability / activity

This is a parallel to a concept in microbiology and extensively used in food safety, called "[water activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_activity)" - bacteria and fungi need water to grow, but this water needs to be "free" for them to use. If the water is bound to a different molecule (e.g. salt or sugar), it is not available to be used.

As the mana inside the creature is currently bound to its structure, it is not available to be used in the same way as "free" mana can be used by a magic user

Another way to think about it is that the creature would have to consume large amounts of its own "flesh" to generate a magical effect and it doesn't want (unconsciously or consciously) to do this - less akin to casting from hit points and more to tearing off its own arm and eating it

### Mana is processed as sustenance, but not manipulated

Since they're made of mana, their bodies process mana as water / food and cannot use mana as anything else, a bit as fishes and water. It is all around them, it is how they move, eat, drink, breathe, but very few fishes do something else with water (e.g. pufferfish).

Most of them use structures in their own bodies for offense / defense, like poison, teeth, spines, colors, etc.